# OpenGL fold/reduce implementation?

Tags: arrays, opengl, functional-programming, gpgpu

I've figure out how to translate the higher order functions [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) and [filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28higher-order_function%29) into OpenGL code by using transform feedback (or by rendering to a texture).  I'd also like to be able to use [fold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29), but I have no idea how this would work.  Let's assume that the operation is associative, so I don't care if it's a left fold or a right fold or some nondeterministic mix.

Examples of fold operations:

- Calculate the smallest AABB containing a set of points (fold over a vertex array).
- Calculate the brightest value in a texture (fold over a texture).

Or is this not feasible without OpenCL or CUDA?

Answer (score 5):

If your operation is associative you can reduce/fold your data by repeatedly rendering to a smaller texture. In each pass you combine a number of texels from the previous pass. You read the data from the previous pass by binding it as a texture for your fragment shader.

For example if you wanted to compute the average of an image of 128x128 values you could first render to a texture of 64x64 where you average 4 texels in the input texture for each texel in the target texture.

A typical example is blurring an image.